# How to index an array by known values

Tags: python, numpy, function, loops, sequence

I have a 2D array composed of times on the left and masses on the right. I want to filter the array to 10 known values of 1 year. So my expected/desired output is the following:

```
array([[ 3.64990e+02, -4.09452e+06],
       [ 7.29730e+02, -5.45551e+06],
       [ 1.09450e+03, -6.39009e+06],
       [ 1.45910e+03, -7.15813e+06],
       [ 1.82380e+03, -7.87166e+06],
       [ 2.18860e+03, -8.58857e+06],
       [ 2.55340e+03, -9.33691e+06],
       [ 2.91820e+03, -1.01254e+07],
       [ 3.28310e+03, -1.09508e+07],
       [ 3.64790e+03, -1.18056e+07]])
```

As you can see, the numbers on the left are 1, 2, 3,..., 10 years in days. I want the numbers on the right which correspond to each of these years. Here is an example of what the data is like at the start and end of the array:

```
n = con = np.stack((times, mass), axis=1)
print(n)
[[ 2.77990e-01 -3.58090e+01]
 [ 5.55970e-01 -9.10160e+01]
 [ 8.33960e-01 -1.70890e+02]
 ...
 [ 3.64960e+03 -1.18096e+07]
 [ 3.64990e+03 -1.18103e+07]
 [ 3.65000e+03 -1.18106e+07]
```

Here is how I tried to index it for the desired values and it did not work:

```
for ti, mi in n:
    for mi in [365,365*2,365*3,365*4,365*5,365*6,365*7,365*8,365*9,365*10]:
        print(ti,mi)

365 -35.809
730 -35.809
1095 -35.809
1460 -35.809
1825 -35.809
2190 -35.809
2555 -35.809
2920 -35.809
3285 -35.809
3650 -35.809
365 -91.016
730 -91.016
1095 -91.016
1460 -91.016
1825 -91.016
2190 -91.016
2555 -91.016
2920 -91.016
3285 -91.016
3650 -91.016
365 -170.89
730 -170.89
1095 -170.89
1460 -170.89
1825 -170.89
2190 -170.89
2555 -170.89
2920 -170.89
3285 -170.89
3650 -170.89
365 -282.73
```

It starts repeating and the values on the right are incorrect. I'm not a programmer, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome Luther ! Please give some insights or example values of what is your expected output. That may make us understand better !

Comment: Hi, thanks. I updated my original post. Hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: Please check the posted solution ! If it helps please mark it as accepted with an upvote so it would be helpful for others too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per my understanding you have `time` and `masses` as `2d array` and you want to filter the values based on `time` which is your `first element` in every `sub-array` then below code should work.

```py
num_of_years = 10
for ti, mi in n:
    if ti in list(range(365,365*(num_of_years+1),365)):
        print(ti,mi)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's very close, but for some reason it doesn't print out the first two times, which are `365` and `730`. The list you used obviously prints out the times I want to index by, so I don't understand what's going wrong. This is the output:

`1095.0 -6391350.0
1460.0 -7159800.0
2190.0 -8591360.0
3285.0 -10955300.0
3650.0 -11810600.0`

Comment: Can you please share your array of `n`

Comment: It's 13000+ data points. Here is a google drive link if you're still interested:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z2-Y1oXzMpYBEMMqpplOVtGbvMCIaZUs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The reason why its not showing up cause, the code checks for specific values like `365, 730, 1095....` but the data you shared from csv do not have specific rounded off values and has `trailing decimals` in the first two values - `365.27, 730.01` and for rest of values it has no trailing decimals. Please refer this image - https://postimg.cc/WFBScy8r

Comment: I get it. That's what I suspected. I guess pandas and numpy can't handle floats like that. I had no idea pandas was that intelligent - thanks for the screenshot and thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Welcome, hope that it was helpful. Also its not with the pandas or numpy, if you see in the code there is an `if` condition. That if condition checks for specific `int` values hence the bug.